# Mongo shell exit value controlled from JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, bash, mongodb

I have a bash script (`task.sh`) that executes a JavaScript script (`clean.js`) through mongo shell. The purpose of `clean.js` is to do some checking on a DB and, if the check is ok, remove it.

The content of `task.sh` script is:

```
mongo localhost clean.js
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Database was removed"
else
  echo "Database check failed"
fi
```

The problem is that I don't know how to control the exit value of the `mongo localhost clean.js` command (I mean, the exit value that bash puts in [`$?` variable](https://www.mylinuxplace.com/bash-special-variables/)) from `clean.js`.

Any help of example to do so, please? Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear... could you provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: The script checks the existente of a given DB. If the database exists, it deletes it and the return value should be 0. If the database didn't exist, it should return a non 0 value. That way, the caller of `mongo localhost script.js` can decide what to do next depending on the value `$?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the **`quit()`** function with specific exit code to achieve this:

**script.js**:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Database was removed"
  quit(0)
else
  echo "Database check failed"
  quit(1)
fi
```

The exit code will then be stored in `$?` variable:

```
> mongo script.js --quiet
> echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatelly, getting the output that way doesn't suffices my use case. I need to use the bash retval "interface" based on `$?`...

Comment: @fgalan what does `$?` mean ? Could you add an example on how you intend to use it ?

Comment: Thansk for the feedback. I have re-written the original question to make the point clearer. By `$?` I'm referring to the bash variable used to hold the exit value of last executed command (https://www.mylinuxplace.com/bash-special-variables/)